# Spallation of Lithium by GeV protons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, accelerator-physics

If you direct a beam of, say 400 keV protons, against a Lithium target, you induce fusion reactions. This is the well known Cockcroft-Walton experiment.

Now I would like to ask if you can induce spallation of Lithium (with irregular fragments) by using GeV protons or other particles of much higher energy?

When I searched for Lithium spallation, all I got were a lot of articles on nucleosynthesis by cosmic rays and such.

Comment: I’d consider it a fission reaction, but ok...

Comment: Jumping from $400\,\mathrm{keV}$ to $1\,\mathrm{GeV}$ in one step is pretty drastic. When I look at the kinds of nuclear data that care about such things you tend to see energy increments of a few to a few tens of $\mathrm{keV}$ at a time.

Comment: Hope this might be helpful: !http://www.iaea.org/inis/collection/NCLCollectionStore/_Public/23/015/23015552.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Considerable work has been done WRT generating high-energy neutrons by bombarding Lithium-7 with protons at energies from the threshold of 1.880612MeV up to (at least) 150MeV. See Mashnik et al. 2008: "7Li(p,n) NUCLEAR DATA LIBRARY FOR INCIDENT PROTON ENERGIES TO 150 MEV", (https://arxiv.org/abs/nucl-th/0011066) and references therein.

Comment: Hi Art: for future reference, please link to the abstract page on Arxiv, as some users may be in mobile devices.